# POST/PUT/DELETE doesn't shown in swagger springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

it's my swagger Config file

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("example.com"))
                .paths(regex("/product.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaData());
    }
    private ApiInfo metaData() {

        return new ApiInfo(
                "Spring Boot REST API",
                "Spring Boot REST API for Online",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of service",
                new Contact("Example Example", "https://springframework.guru/about/", "example@gmail.com"),
                "Apache License Version 2.0",
                "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0");
    }
    }
```

Student Controller

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.example.learnspring.StudentRepository.StudentRepository;
import com.example.learnspring.model.StudentDto;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
public class StudentController {


    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository eRepo;

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public StudentDto save (@RequestBody StudentDto employee) {
        return eRepo.save(employee);
    }


    //@RequestMapping("/greeting/{lang}")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting/{lang}", method = RequestMethod.GET)


    @GetMapping("/student")
    public List<StudentDto> get () {
        return eRepo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public StudentDto get (@PathVariable int id) {
        Optional<StudentDto> employee = eRepo.findById(id);
        if (employee.isPresent()) {
            return employee.get();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Not found for the id "+id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/student/{id}")
    public StudentDto update (@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody StudentDto employee) {
        employee.setId(id);
        return eRepo.save(employee);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/student/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> delete (@PathVariable int id) {
        eRepo.deleteById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        

}
}
```

StudentDTO class

```
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level= AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class StudentDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    @NotNull(message = "Age cannot be null")
    @Min(value = 15, message = "Age should not be less than 15")
    @Max(value = 65, message = "Age should not be greater than 65")
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

My Repository

```
import com.example.learnspring.model.StudentDto;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDto, Integer> {
}
```

Myapplication class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class LearnSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LearnSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
server.port=9090
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>LearnSpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>LearnSpring</name>
    <description>LearnSpring</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
        <swagger.version>3.0.0</swagger.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--springfox dependencies for api documentations in swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
            <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run this application everything looks fine but I can't see the POST/PUT/or DELETE. I try to many things I find from Internet but it doesn't work. I new on this topic. I actually want to wrote null inputs and get exceptions for exception handling.

Comment: If you have `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency in your pom.xml and you're not using it then remove and try.

Comment: I don't have  **spring-boot-starter-actuator**  in my pom.xml file(I'll add my pom.xml to question also I forgot to add)

Comment: you have defined `springfox-swagger-ui` and `springfox-swagger2` twice in pom.xml ?

Comment: I fix it moment ago. I accidentally added twice and didn't notice(it was disabled because of the IDE anyway)

Comment: Just add this and check it works ```@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you for solution. But why it didn't work in my example? If you have an idea can you tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your Docket Configuration has specified a regex pattern for `product`

```
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("example.com"))
                .paths(regex("/product.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaData());
    }
```

But your controllers don't have any APIs with `/product`.
Thus you're not able to see APIs in swagger documentation.

Try with below configuration and see if it shows you all endpoints and then start working around regex configurations.

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```

Above configuration matches all the API paths in your web application basically anywhere.

You can access your APIs at
Change the `APPLICATION_PORT` and `CONTEXT-PATH`

http://localhost:{{APPLICATION_PORT}}/{{CONTEXT-PATH}}/swagger-ui.html